# Automate access token retieval using python similar to doing manually in Postman

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, amazon-cognito, rauth

Here is my current workflow. I have an OAuth app with AWS Cognito doing the authorization. I have the following details for the app.

```
Grant Type Authorization code
Callback URL https://abcd.com/callback
Auth URL https://appid.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize
Access Token URL https://appid.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
Client ID abcdeftlh2n95llrfsjq2q
Client Secret None 
Scope openid profile user/*.*
Client Authentication send client credentials in the body
```

And once I enter this information in Postman and click “Get new Access Token” button, it opens a new window and takes me to cognito login page where I can enter username and password for an user and if the details are valid, it would return an access token. I can then use this access token under Authorization tab to make GET or POST calls to my app and get data.

I am trying to write an automated test for this to make sure this functionality doesn't break in the future. I started off with requests library to send a get request using token URL and username and password as auth parameter, but it gave me “Invalid Request” response.

I looked up for other alternates and then came across rauth library and used something similar to what they have in their documentation and getting the same invalid request as response.

Here is my code for the rauth in python

```
from rauth import OAuth2Service
cognito_data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'scope': scope
    }


# auth = OAuth2Service(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, access_token_url=cognito_token_url, authorize_url=cognito_auth_url, redirect_uri='https://abcd.com/callback')

# session = auth.get_auth_session(data=cognito_data, decoder = json.loads)
```

All the values for variables like client_id, client_secret (this was before I set it to None) and others are set correctly before this block of code to match with what I have used in Postman.

Then I tried using boto3 to get the access token using below code.
`import boto3

```
    username = "blabla"
    password = "Password123!"
    user_pool = "us-east-2_0OGPI"
    client_id = "abcdef4q01tlh2n95llrfsjq2q"
    region = "us-east-2"
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='prof1')
    auth_data = { 'USERNAME':username, 'PASSWORD':password }
    provider_client=session.client('cognito-idp', region_name=region)
    resp = provider_client.initiate_auth(AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH', AuthParameters=auth_data, ClientId=client_id)
    token = resp['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']
    print(token)

    import requests

    url = "https://auth.appid.domain.io/oauth2/Patient"

    payload={}
    headers = {
    'Authorization': token
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(response.status_code)

    print(response)
```

This actually retrieves the access token but when I try to call the GET using requests using that token, I get a 403. If I replace the token from above step with the token I am getting from Postman, it gives a 200. I am not sure what I am missing. Most examples I have come across online don't seem to be using an username and password for authorization.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks